# Why is it OK to pass mismatch argument into isdigit function?

Tags: c

I'm new to C, sorry if my question is a little bit strange.

the signature of `isdigital` function is:

```
int isdigit(int arg);
```

but I saw a lot of cases that a char can also be argument, for example:

```
char c = '5';
printf("Result when numeric character is passed: %d", isdigit(c));
```

`c` is a char, not an interger, how can it can be used in this way? does implicit casting from `char` to `int` occur here?

Comment: An implicit cast takes place.

Comment: The C language provides the four basic arithmetic type specifiers `char`, int, float and double, and the modifiers signed, unsigned, short, and long. [check here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_data_types)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `c` is a `char`, not an integer, how can it can be used in this way?

The `char` is *converted* to an `int`.  When `char` is *signed*, this is no problem - the value converts without issue.

When `char` is *unsigned*, except on rare machines, again no issue as all values of `unsigned char` exist in `int`.

Th trick is that `is...(int)` functions are well defined for `int` values in the `unsigned char` range and `EOF` (some negative value), but not all negative values.  Best for `char` to be cast to the `unsigned char` first.

```
char c = '5';
// printf("Result when numeric character is passed: %d", isdigit(c));
printf("Result when numeric character is passed: %d", isdigit((unsigned char) c));
```

Note: the return value of `isdigit(int)` and friends are zero (not a digit) or some non-zero value (is a digit).  The exact non-zero value is not so important as much as it is non-zero (true).

> does implicit casting from char to int occur here?

No, type conversion occurs.

Comment: Also note that `isdigit` should be passed an `unsigned char` value per the C standard. Passing a signed `char` will not have any problem with the conversion to `int`, but, if it is negative, `isdigit` is permitted to fail. Common implementations may handle signed values, though.