# Are the digits in a given string strictly ascending?

Tags: c, string, function, pointers, pointer-arithmetic

I am a beginner programmer and I'm having trouble with this task.
I have to write a function that checks if the digits in the given string are strictly ascending, or better say is each digit larger than the previous one.
Function returns true or false, but it also has to be able to return -1 if there are no numbers in the string.

So for the string: "a1b2c3d" the function should return 1,

but for "a1b3c3d" the function should return 0 because they are not strictly ascending.

I cannot use arrays or create new strings.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<ctype.h>
//we have to enter our strings like this
void unesi(char niz[],int velicina)
{
    char znak=getchar();
    if(znak=='\n')
    znak=getchar();

    int i=0;
    while(i<velicina-1 && znak!='\n')
    {
        niz[i]=znak;
        i++;
        znak=getchar();
    }
    niz[i]='\0';
}
//function checks if the string contains any digits
int cifre(const char *s)
{
    int istina=1;
     
    if(isdigit(*s++))
    istina=0;
    
    return istina;
}
int srce(const char *s)
{
    int broj=1,istina=0;
    if(cifre(s)==1)
    return -1;
    else
    {
       while(*s!='\0')
       {
            if(isdigit(*s)==1)
            {
                if(*s<broj)
                {
                    broj=*s;
                    istina=1;
                    s++;
                }
            }
            else
            s++;
       }
        return istina;
    }
}
int main() {
    char a[100];
    unesi(a,100);
    printf("%d",srce(a));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are you not allowed to use `fgets()` to read a whole line?

Comment: `unesi()` is not saving the first character into `niz`

Comment: You forgot to ask a question. What are you specifically having trouble with?

Comment: Having answered a question, yesterday, that was coded very, very similar to this one, only to see the work I'd put in diagnosing the OP code, and adding a correct minimal solution, **deleted** by the OP, I'm in no mood to tackle this question... "Do my homework for me, please." is not the purpose of SO.

Comment: There may be (many) other problems, but your `cifre()` function only checks the first character of the string.

Answer (score 0):

Logic is quite simple.

The function returns -1 if there is no digits
1 if they are sorted in ascending order or zero if not

```
int isAsc(char *str)
{
    int result = -1;
    int last = -1;

    while(*str)
    {
        if(isdigit((unsigned char)*str))
        {
            result = 1;
            if(last != -1)
            {
                if(*str - '0' < last)
                {
                    result = 0;
                    break;
                }
            }
            last = *str - '0';
        }
        str++;
    }
    return result;
}


int main(void)
{
    printf("%d\n", isAsc("dsfgdfgdfgfgd"));
    printf("%d\n", isAsc("d0sfg1dfg4dfg7fgd"));
    printf("%d\n", isAsc("d0sfg1dfg4dfg7f2gd"));
}
```

Comment: Should be <= last

Comment: @user18533375 depending if 112233 is ascending or not. IMO is

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> //we have to enter our strings like this
> ```

It's unclear to me if the *whole* `unesi` function is given as part of the assignment and can't be modified or not, so I won't comment it.

Just read about `fgets`, in the future.

---

> I cannot use arrays

Well, I guess that restriction is somehow relaxed:

```
char a[100];
```

That's "literally" an array of 100 chars. Hopefully, it will be null-terminated, so that we can consider it a "string".

---

> ```
> //function checks if the string contains any digits
> ```

That comment is lying, `cifre` is only checking the *first* character, because there is no loop, nor any calling to a function that could traverse a `char` array inside it.

Besides, instead of checking beforehand if the string contains *any* digit, you could start searching for the *first* digit and then check if the *other* digits are in strictly ascending order.

---

In `srce` function, we can find

```
int srce(const char *s)
{
    int broj=1, istina=0;
    //  ^^^^^^        ^^     Note that the starting value of broj is 1.
 
    // [...]

    while(*s!='\0')         
    {
        if(isdigit(*s)==1)
        {
            if( *s < broj )
            { //^^^^^^^^^    Are any of '0', '1', '2'... less than 1?
              //             Is this supposed to be the path taken when
              //             the digits are not in STRICTLY ascending order?
              //             In that case you should check if the current digit
              //             is less than OR EQUAL to the previous one.
                broj=*s;
                istina=1;  // Shouldn't it be 0 when the order is not correct?
                s++;       // Shouldn't the traversal of the string just end now?  
            }
        }
        else
            s++;
    }
    return istina;
}
```

Another subtle issue with the previous code is that `isdigit`<sup>1</sup> returns a **non-zero value** if the character is a numeric character, not necessarly **1**.

---

<sup>(1) About `isdigit` call, see also: [Why is it OK to pass mismatch argument into isdigit function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63915898/why-is-it-ok-to-pass-mismatch-argument-into-isdigit-function)</sup>